# CTS and xPath both necessary?

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have the following CTS search query:

```
cts:search(/parent, 
    cts:and-query((
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('parent'), xs:QName('attr'), 'value'),
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('child'), xs:QName('attr-1'), 'value-2'),
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('child'), xs:QName('attr-2'), 'value-3')
    ))
)/child[@attr-1 eq 'value-2' and @attr-2 eq "value-3"]

(: Returns /parent/child elements matching criteria :)
```

I have some qualifiers on the parent, as well as qualifiers on the children.  The end result I want is just the children though.  In order to do that, as you can see from above, I have to:

- Search for documents that match parent criteria + children criteria
- After getting that document, filter out the children by the same criteria logic as above

This works, but it seems really dumb that I must have the same logic in the cts:query as I do on the xPath for the children.  The logic is duplicated unnecessarily.

**Is there a way that I can do this all in the cts:query, and not have to have additional xPath expressions, as in the sample above?**

---

This is similar to what I want, but it doesn't work for the problem specified in the comments:

```
cts:search(/parent/child, 
    cts:and-query((
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('parent'), xs:QName('attr'), 'value'), (: The problem is this line... I can't filter by the parent, as it is above the scope of my first parameter (/parent/rule) :)
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('child'), xs:QName('attr-1'), 'value-2'),
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('child'), xs:QName('attr-2'), 'value-3')
    ))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still query the parent, even if your search is across the child:

```
cts:search(/parent/child, 
    cts:and-query((
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('parent'), xs:QName('attr'), 'value'),
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('child'), xs:QName('attr-1'), 'value-2'),
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('child'), xs:QName('attr-2'), 'value-3')
    ))
)
```

This will run as a filtered search, but since you were manually doing the filtering anyway, the performance should be roughly equivalent.

**Update:**

I tested this and the above assertion is wrong. I thought it was right, but evidently `cts:search` filtering will filter results that don't match on the searchable expression exactly.  A parent would be outside of the scope of the searchable expression.

Ideally, you would break up your documents on the `child` element, but you can at least remove the overlapping queries and XPath like this:

```
cts:search(/parent/child, 
    cts:and-query((
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('child'), xs:QName('attr-1'), 'value-2'),
        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName('child'), xs:QName('attr-2'), 'value-3')
    ))
)[parent::parent/@attr = 'value']
```

Comment: This is not working for me.  When I have `/parent` as the searchable expression, I get the parent back from the cts:search.  When I put in `/parent/child` as the searchable expression, I don't get anything back.  The cts:query itself never changes, all I am changing is the searchable expression.  When I have the `/parent/child`, it does not work.  My assumption is the first element-attribute-value-query on the parent throws everything off, since it is not below the searchable expression(?)

Comment: Thanks for your update wst.  You could also easily reverse the logic, and grab the parent from the cts:search, then filter the children using xPath.  Where you have filtered the children, in my case, will actually be faster, since it's more specific than parents.  I was still hoping (as per the question) to solve all of this in the cts:search for purely stylistic reasons, but perhaps it is not possible.  Is the computation cost the same of filtering a cts:search as it is for filtering by an xPath expression?

Comment: @CtheGood Computationally, making cts:search do as much of the heavy lifting as possible is the best strategy. All of the results it can return *unfiltered* will be resolved using only indexes, so they'll be very fast. If you have to use filtering via cts:search or manually via XPath then the database has to 1) select more documents than it might otherwise and 2) load them into memory to perform filtering. There is no general rule for how to maximize the former and minimize the latter - it just depends on your documents, so testing different approaches is about all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

wst gave you the answer. However, this all comes up from needing filtering. In MarkLogic, the idea is that one document should reflect one 'record'. Is it possible to refactor your documents to avoid the need for filtering in the fist place?

Comment: No, it is not.  My documents are already very simple, where each document has the root element with only 1 deep children (ie <parent><child/><child/><child/></parent>).  The parent has attributes, as do all the children.  I want to get just a few targeted children of the already target parent.  I've always had to do it with double logic - cts:search on parent, then filtering by same logic using xPath.  But, I'd like to consolidate.

Comment: @CtheGood Elaborating on David's suggestion using a relational analogy, in MarkLogic it's best to think of documents as rows, not tables. For ideal query performance you want a one to one relationship between the data you need to query and a single document. In your case, I might make <child> a document (or use fragment roots...but be careful) and propagate (duplicate) any data important for querying from the parent to the child documents. This type of "denormalization" is very common practice in ML.

Comment: And of course -this is balance. Not quite an art -but some personal choices come into play. You must also consider that you don;t necessarily want tiny fragments in MarkLogic, so if the child documents are 'tiny' (see docs for guidance), then packaging them together up to a certain size and applying filtering is then a viable option. Even triples in ML (3 elements and a parent element) are stored by approx 100 in a fragment rather than individually when they are imported, for example.